# How to get the IP address of the default gateway *reliably* on Android 5+?

Tags: android

How can I get the IP address of the [default gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway) in the network that my Android device is connected to?

I appreciate that this has been asked before on SO, but none of the solutions I've found are reliable enough:

- Most solutions recommend using [`DHCPInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/DhcpInfo#gateway), but what if my device isn't using DHCP?
- Some recommend getting the DNS server, but you could override the DNS servers in the WiFi connection settings.
- I could take the device's internal IP address (e.g., `192.168.0.2`) and replace the last octet with a `1` because that's *usually* the IP address of the default gateway. But not always, especially if the gateway is another Android phone (based on my tests on Pixel 2, for example, the WiFi hotspot will assign itself a random IP address in the range `192.168.43.0/24`).

I can reliably get the IP address for the default gateway on Linux by running `route -n`. Is there any reliable way to get it on Android 5+?

Comment: Ever find an answer?

Comment: No. I'm inclined to just go for the DHCPInfo option, even though I don't like it for the reason above.

Comment: same here. I need a solution for both wifi and cell networks. :(